# Possible to join back broken keyboard internal inlay?

Tags: keyboard

Inside a keyboard there is a inlay of circuits, or traces, not sure the correct term.

[image: inlay, or traces]

But if a part of a line has deteriorated leaving (part) of the keyboard non-functional since the circuit can no longer connect to that area, is it possible to fix it?

For example apply some contact material to join the broken line back together.

If so, I'm curious what material and instructions on use.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's *possible*, but might not be worth the time and expense. You could try a [rear car window defroster grid repair kit](https://www.pepboys.com/permatex-complete-rear-window-defogger-repair-kit/product/9310122?tab=tab4) for ~US$15, but can get a new keyboard for not much more. If you have some future use for the conductive paint left over from the repair, or want to do this as a learning experience or because that model keyboard is not available, or just to protest the throw-away economy, though, let us know how this works and how durable the repair is.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm still mulling the whole thing over because like you said a keyboard isn't much more. I'll update if it I do buy it and try it out.